# single msi for 32-bit and 64-bit depend on target machine

Tags: wix, 64-bit, 32-bit

Using WIX, I need to create an msi or exe that should work in both 32-bit and
64-bit machines depend on system.

Comment: If you create a 32 bit package, it will work fine mostly in 64 bit configuration as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, because the MSI format requires you to specify the processor architecture. So you must create two separate .msi files, but you can at least generate them from the same project file in Wix, which avoids some duplicate work.

I use this:

```
<?if $(var.Platform) = x64 ?>
<?define ProductName = "InsomniacGeek: Windows Setup Test (64 bit)" ?>
<?define Win64 = "yes" ?>
<?define PlatformProgramFilesFolder = "ProgramFiles64Folder" ?>
<?else ?>
<?define ProductName = "InsomniacGeek: Windows Setup Test" ?>
<?define Win64 = "no" ?>
<?define PlatformProgramFilesFolder = "ProgramFilesFolder" ?>
<?endif ?>


<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Platform="$(var.Platform)"/>
```

Then you would have to build the project and create a 32-bit Msi and 64-bit Msi.

Comment: Using Burn you could then create a bootstrapper to check the OS and install the appropriate msi.

Comment: Platform="$(var.Platform)" showing that the platform supported by the package. Use of this attribute is discouraged; instead, specify the -arch switch at the candle.exe command line or the InstallerPlatform property in a .wixproj MSBuild project.

Comment: I only get a squiggly line and a warning in Votive because the literal text $(var.Platform) isn't one of the platform enumeration values defined in the XML Schema for WiX source files. Once the preprocessor finishes with the file, the attribute's value is valid and candle will happily accept it. What version of Wix are you using?

Comment: WiX v3.7 released. I also get a squiggly line and a warning. Shoud i choose  a 'x86' option present in my Configuration Manager for getting a 32 bit msi, or choose a 'x64' option for a 64 bit msi?

Comment: You will have to build both.